# How do I store <input> "names" as properties of an object and then store the matching <input> "value" as the values of that object's properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to essentially build an object dynamically where a property be the inputs name and the value of that property will be the inputs value.

Here's HTML

```
<form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>form</legend>
                    <label>First<input type="text" value="null" name="first"/></label>
                    <label>Last<input type="text" value="null" name="last"/></label>
                    <label>Email<input type="text" value="null" name="email"/></label>

                    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using so far.
I have stored the values in and names in separate arrays.  Is there a way to create some sort of associative array or to create an object where property names are taken from one array and values taken from another?

```
        var values = new Array();
    var names = new Array();

    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

            values = [];
            names = [];

            $('form input').not('[type="submit"]').each(function(){
            values.push($(this).val());

            });


            $('form input').not('[type="submit"]').each(function(){
            names.push($(this).attr("name"));

            });

    });
```

I've also tried the .serializeArray() and it returns an array of Objects.  But then I have no idea how to pull all of the key/value pairs out of that object and into a new one.

The end goal is to not send this data over ajax but to send to a third party that aggregates data for analytics. Please help.  I'm self taught and totally lost.  Haha.  Thanks

PS

I tried this

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var input = $("form").serializeArray();
            $.each(input, function(i, field){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(input[i]));
            });
        });
```

but it returns this

```
{"name":"first","value":"null"}
{"name":"last","value":"null"}
{"name":"email","value":"null"}
```

which seems to be equally as unhelpful.  Haha.

I would love to be able to get an outcome as such

```
{
  "first" : "null",
  "last" : "null",
  "email" : "null"
}
```

Comment: How do you find the relationship between the name and the value from two independent arrays?  Can you post your expected output out of your example html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and then [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that to an object or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). For example

```
$('form').on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let values = $(this).serializeArray().reduce((map, input) => {
        let value;
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(input.name)) {
            value = Array.isArray(map[input.name]) ?
                map[input.name] : [map[input.name]];
            value.push(input.value);
        } else {
            value = input.value;
        }
        map[input.name] = value;
        return map;
    }, {});
})
```

This handles `<select multiple>` and `<input type="checkbox">` elements by setting the named value as an array.

JSFiddle demo here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/wmjeh5Lv/1/

---

Legacy version

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var values = $(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(map, input) {
        var value;
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(input.name)) {
            value = Array.isArray(map[input.name]) ?
                map[input.name] : [map[input.name]];
            value.push(input.value);
        } else {
            value = input.value;
        }
        map[input.name] = value;
        return map;
    }, {});
})
```

Comment: I love the use of a map.  This also points me in a solid direction for what to read up on next.  I appreciate the help, Phil!

Comment: @Tamb you're welcome. Just be mindful that this won't work correctly for `<select multiple>` or checkbox elements. Let me know if you need support for those

Comment: @Tamb updated to handle multi-selects and checkboxes

Comment: @Tamb I removed the `Map` example. It wasn't adding anything and only makes transferring the data object more difficult

Comment: let's say I needed a json object. Could I forego the map function and instead use a JSON.stringify() as the callback in reduce?

Comment: @Tamb the result of `values` will be a plain JavaScript object so you can stringify it if you want. See the jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1):

This should work, though realistically I don't understand the need for it. Check your browser's console. It gave me:
`{first: "null", last: "null", email: "null"}`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var arrObj = {};
    $(this).find('input:not(:submit)').each(function(i, el) {
      el = $(el);
      arrObj[el.attr('name')] = el.val();
    });
    console.log(arrObj);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>form</legend>
    <label>First
      <input type="text" value="null" name="first" />
    </label>
    <label>Last
      <input type="text" value="null" name="last" />
    </label>
    <label>Email
      <input type="text" value="null" name="email" />
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

## Quick bit about Scope and Functions

Note: I am not a javascript expert, I have no formal education on it these are simply the things I've learned in using javascript.

1. If you define a variable **outside** a function, you can use it inside*

Using the same code I gave you, you could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arrObj = {};
  //Notice, arrObj is now defined OUTSIDE of our form.onsubmit function
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find('input:not(:submit)').each(function(i, el) {
      el = $(el);
      arrObj[el.attr('name')] = el.val();
    });
    console.log(arrObj);
  });

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(arrObj);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>form</legend>
    <label>First
      <input type="text" value="null" name="first" />
    </label>
    <label>Last
      <input type="text" value="null" name="last" />
    </label>
    <label>Email
      <input type="text" value="null" name="email" />
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<button>Click me and Check Console<small>*Must click submit button first</small></button>
```

2. This goes up as far as you want it to.

Got a variable you defined outside the `$(document).ready(...)` and you want to use it? Go ahead. Javascript don't care.

3. When in doubt, create another function that you can return from somewhere else, like so (this involves using `$.fn.extend()` to add a new method to every jquery object)

```js
$.fn.extend({
  formObject: function() {
    var arrObj = {};
    
    $(this).find('input:not(:submit)').each(function(i, el) {
      el = $(el);
      arrObj[el.attr('name')] = el.val();
    });
    return arrObj;
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    alert('check console');
    console.log($('form').formObject());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>form</legend>
    <label>First
      <input type="text" value="null" name="first" />
    </label>
    <label>Last
      <input type="text" value="null" name="last" />
    </label>
    <label>Email
      <input type="text" value="null" name="email" />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

These are not the *only* ways, and if I am honest I don't even think they're the **best** ways, but they're the fastest ways using what we already have.

Comment: This will miss `<textarea>` elements

Comment: true, but I'm mimicking his original code as it only calls for inputs.

Comment: Thank you.  The idea is to create json objects with dynamic property names and dynamic values to send to a third party.  I'm getting the same thing in my console.  Thank you for this.  But I'm wondering how to then share this object with other parts of my program?  Could you maybe point me in the right direction?  Been searching for hours

Comment: Depends where you're trying to use the info. Give me a second my comp restarted

Comment: @Jhecht that is amazing.  I really really appreciate this help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the submit button if the only need it go generate an object?

So here is my try only to generate the output without arrays ...

```js
function generate() {

  var obj = {};
  
  $('form input').not('[type="submit"]')
    .each((index, input) => obj[input.name] = input.value);
  
  $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>form</legend>
    <label>First<input type="text" value="null" name="first"/></label>
    <label>Last<input type="text" value="null" name="last"/></label>
    <label>Email<input type="text" value="null" name="email"/></label>

    <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```